Create Workbook and Add Rows in MS Excel 365 using Java
I want to create a workbook in Excel 365 and write data in it with Java. I tried using HSSFWorkbook and XSSFWorkbook both, But getting below error while writing. How can I create a workbook and add rows in it using Java?
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: "file path" (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:289)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:230)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:118)
    at com.example.ExcelWorkbook.CreateExcelWorkBook.main(CreateExcelWorkBook.java:28)

I tried creating the workbook using Java HSSFWorkbook api, but it is not working,
public class CreateExcelWorkBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("No.");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Address");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Email");

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)1);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("1");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Sankumarsingh");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("India");
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue("sankumarsingh@gmail.com");

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("file path");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
    }
}


FileOutputStream takes in a File object. In your code pasted here, you just passed in text instead of an object

Refer to documentation for class java.io.FileOutputStream: Creates a file output stream to write to the file with the specified name. ... If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.
